# When to image resize, custom lines drawn on image should also resize in wpf/c#

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I have a wpf application. There is a image control that shows a image. I have put a canvas on top and I draw line on it. With double click I increase the size of the image control. Hence image in it also increases to fit the image control but the size of the line drawn on the canvas does not change.

I want when I change the size of image shapes like line or rectangle, drawn on image also changes in proportion.

Comment: Did you try something? Let's see...

Comment: thanks Marco for your reply. I have no idea how to do this relative position of shapes on image. I can draw line on canvas using mouse up and down events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to store coords of graphical objects you draw manually.
When you resize image you have to create graphical objects from scratch changing their coords according to zoom factor.
Probably you could use `Matrix` object to make it easier..

Comment: Thanks Marco again. Suppose I am drawing a line. I store the line start and end point. How can I calculate the zoom factor of image?

Comment: @user370267: easy!! Store image control width and height at the beginning; then, getting resize event, calc new zoom `Xfactor = new_width / orig_width` and `Yfactor = new_height / orig_height`. Use these factors to _zoom_ your graphical objects too...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the canvas has the same initial size as the image control.  When zooming the image control, just use a scale transform and apply the same scale transform to the canvas.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can I achieve with code that you said? Sorry I did not get fully.